# How to extract a range of number from two files?

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, perl

I'm trying to extract the number range from two files.

$ cat file1.txt

> chr1 69509
>   chr1 69511
>   chr1 71000
>   chr1 358112
>   chr1 586874
>   chr1 744200
>   .
>   .
>   .

$cat file2.txt

> chr1 69091 70005
>   chr1 358070 358183
>   chr1 586842 586955
>   chr1 744195 744343
>   .
>   .
>   .

Desired output :

> 69509 chr1 69091 70005
>   69511 chr1 69091 70005
>   71000 out of range
>   358112 chr1 358070 358183
>   586874 chr1 586842 586955
>   744200 chr1 744195 744343

Below is my awk code.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{x[$1] = $2; next;}{for (i in x) {if (x[i] > $2 && x[i] < $3)print x[i], $1,$2,$3;else{print x[i], "out of range"}}}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

However, the output returned by this code contains only the data of the last NR.

For example,

> 744200 out of range
>   744200 out of range
>   744200 out of range
>   744200 chr1 744195 744343

I guess it is related to NR and FNR but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: How big are the two files? How many lines in each? It matters if one or both are huge.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are keying your array `x` on `$1` which is the same `chr1` for all the lines in the first file. So on every line the array contents are indexed based on the same key and overwritten with the value in `$2`. So by the end of the file you have one entry in the array `x['chr1']=744200`

You need to store the line uniquely. Store the key as a tuple `$1 FS $2` and modify your logic to

```
awk 'NR == FNR { x[$1 FS $2] = $2; next }{ 
     for (key in x) { 
       split(key, arr)
       if (arr[2] > $2 && arr[2] < $3) 
           print arr[2], $0 
       else {
           print arr[2], "out of range"
       }
     }
}' file1 file2
```

To improve the logic to do the range check only on lines where the first column is the same for both the files, add a condition to the `if` as

```
if ( (arr[2] > $2 && arr[2] < $3) && ( $1 == arr[1] ) )
```

Comment: This would essentially store the first file in memory. If the second file is smaller, it may be better to do the inverse, i.e. to store the ranges, and then parse the first file.  If both are _really large_, it may be better to process them chromosome by chromosome.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file2 ranges don't overlap, like in your example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF==3 { beg=$2; end=$3; all=$0; next }
{ print $2, ( ($2 >= beg) && ($2 <= end) ? all : "out of range" ) }

$ sort -sk2n file2 file1 | awk -f tst.awk
69509 chr1 69091 70005
69511 chr1 69091 70005
71000 out of range
358112 chr1 358070 358183
586874 chr1 586842 586955
744200 chr1 744195 744343
```

It uses GNU sort for `-s` ("stable sort") to ensure the file2 entry is printed before the `file1` entry in the case of identical `$2`s.